# Trace an image using Photoshop without the pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I drew an image of a centipede and scanned it to my computer. My objective is to trace the image like how this guy in the video is doing it. I tried to google trace image in Photoshop but i keep finding ways to trace the image using the pen tool. If you look in this video the person is not using the pen tool to trace over the image. My question is how is he tracing this centipede?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcyzL8CY2NQ

Comment: That video is in Illustrator, not Photoshop

Answer (score 0):

Can see in the video he has the Brush tool selected. He's just using the Brush tool on a new layer.

Answer (score 0):

He paints In illustrator. You see, how illustrator fixes all the strokes to a consistent selected brush form just after the stroke is drawn. Then the exessive too long stroke tails are timmed off and some occasional paths are  edited for the wanted form.

Everyhing until this but after the creation of the original image is quite mechanical. The hard part is the coloring - choosing the judicious colors, gradients and glows. That simply does not succeed without the proper visio of the wanted result - just like the creation of the original is impossible without the visio.

The tracing is possible in Photoshop, but why? Photoshop is not a tool for vector graphics. You can draw paths nearly as easily with the "Freeform Pen" but to get the colors you should still return to bitmap and that you already have.